# How to make text boxes aligned vertically?

Tags: html, css, textbox, frontend

I have two textboxes on top of each other like so: [image]

the text boxes are postioned in a way where there position depends on the text that comes before it; the longer the text is, the more right the right the text box will be. How can I make it so that the two text boxes are positioned vertically in the same position, stacked on top of each other?

Comment: `Flexbox` or `CSS-Grid` will solve your issue! Please add enough code as debugging details and preferebly shows your attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution is `CSS-Grid` which willc reate a table-like-layout:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

/* counters the linebreak at white-space caused by min-content */
label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<label>Sceenshot 1.png</label>
<input type="text">
<label>Sceen Shot 2022-06-21 at 5.58.05 PM.png</label>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: This is not supported in Baidu Browser 7.12 - https://caniuse.com/css-grid

Comment: which has a global usage of rounded 0%... Every major browser (even deprecated IE) supports it.

Answer (score 0):

1. use [CSS GRID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) with [`grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) for element near the other.

```html
<div id="container" style="
display: grid; 
grid-template-columns: auto 1fr; 
gap: 0.5rem;">

  <!-- 1 -->
  <span>small text</span>
  <input type="text">

  <!-- 2 -->
  <span>longer text, longer text...</span>
  <input type="text">

</div>
```

2. just add `display: grid` to the parent element, if you want every element be one under the other

```html
<div id="container" style="display: grid;">

  <!-- 1 -->
  <span>small text</span>
  <input type="text">

  <!-- 2 -->
  <span>longer text, longer text...</span>
  <input type="text">

</div>
```

3. > I suggest using `<label>` instead of normal `<span>`! to help with accessibility. infact if user click on the `<span>` it will be automatically focused on `<input>`

```html
    <div id="container" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto 1fr; gap: 0.5rem;">

        <!-- 1 -->
        <label for="first-input">
            <span>small text</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="first-input">

        <!-- 2 -->
        <label for="second-input">
            <span>longer text, longer text...</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="second-input">
    </div>
```